# MySQL - JOIN condition & performance issue

Tags: mysql, sql

In [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfaa61/1), I've added data filter  conditions on `employee_name`, `task_date` and `region` in the `JOIN` clause. It seems to me I'm doing something wrong here as, in the output, I can't see the data filtered.

I expect to see data only between the dates `'2015-01-03'` & `'2015-01-06'` whereas the current query is returning data equivalent to the date filter not being present.

Also, is there a better way to write this query as the fiddle only designed to get the correct SQL whereas the data in production environment is worth several years & the query never seems to complete (It could run even more than 30 mins & keep running happily until killed). The database is quite optimized for performance in case someone is wondering if tuning the DB may be an option.

Any pointers would be really helpful here please.

**INPUT/OUTPUT**

[image]

**CODE**

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`task_date` date, `employee_name` varchar(7), `task_name` varchar(55), `region` varchar(100));
INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`task_date`, `employee_name`, `task_name`, `region`)
VALUES
    ('2015-01-01', 'A', 'task A','USA'),
    ('2015-01-01', 'B', 'task B','Russia'),
    ('2015-01-01', 'C', 'task C','USA'),
    ('2015-01-01', 'D', 'task D','USA'),
    ('2015-01-02', 'A', 'task A','Russia'),
    ('2015-01-02', 'B', 'task B','Singapore'),
    ('2015-01-02', 'C', 'task C','USA'),
    ('2015-01-02', 'D', 'task D','USA'),
    ('2015-01-03', 'A', 'task C','Australia'),
    ('2015-01-03', 'B', 'task B','London'),
    ('2015-01-03', 'C', 'task D','USA'),
    ('2015-01-03', 'D', 'task A','USA'),
    ('2015-01-03', 'C', 'task C','London'),
    ('2015-01-04', 'A', 'task B','USA'),
    ('2015-01-04', 'B', 'task A','Singapore'),
    ('2015-01-04', 'C', 'task C','USA'),
    ('2015-01-04', 'D', 'task D','India'),
    ('2015-01-05', 'A', 'task F','USA'),
    ('2015-01-05', 'B', 'task F','USA'),
    ('2015-01-05', 'C', 'task G','China'),
    ('2015-01-05', 'D', 'task B','USA'),
    ('2015-01-06', 'A', 'task Y','USA'),
    ('2015-01-06', 'B', 'task X','USA'),
    ('2015-01-06', 'C', 'task E','USA'),
    ('2015-01-06', 'D', 'task R','USA'),
    ('2015-01-07', 'A', 'task W','China'),
    ('2015-01-07', 'B', 'task O','Russia'),
    ('2015-01-07', 'C', 'task P','USA'),
    ('2015-01-07', 'D', 'task S','London'),
    ('2015-01-07', 'C', 'task E','USA'),
    ('2015-01-08', 'A', 'task E','USA'),
    ('2015-01-08', 'B', 'task W','USA'),
    ('2015-01-08', 'C', 'task C','USA'),
    ('2015-01-08', 'D', 'task B','London');
```

**SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT   task_date, 
         employee_name, 
         Group_concat(task_name) 
FROM     ( 
             SELECT DISTINCT a.task_date, 
                             a.employee_name, 
                             CASE 
                                 WHEN b.employee_name IS NOT NULL
                                     AND c.employee_name IS NULL THEN NULL
                                 ELSE a.task_name
                             END AS task_name 
             FROM forgerock AS a 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN forgerock AS b 
                 ON  a.employee_name = b.employee_name = 'A'
                 AND a.task_date >= '2015-01-03' 
                 AND a.task_date <= '2015-01-06' 
                 AND b.task_date >= '2015-01-03' 
                 AND b.task_date <= '2015-01-06' 
                 AND a.task_date - 1 = b.task_date
                 AND a.region = b.region = 'USA' 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN forgerock AS c 
                 ON  a.employee_name = c.employee_name = 'A'
                 AND a.task_date >= '2015-01-03' 
                 AND a.task_date <= '2015-01-06' 
                 AND c.task_date >= '2015-01-03' 
                 AND c.task_date <= '2015-01-06' 
                 AND a.task_date - 1 = c.task_date
                 AND a.task_name <> c.task_name 
                 AND a.region = c.region = 'USA' 
             ORDER BY a.task_date, 
                      a.employee_name, 
                      a.task_name) AS temp 
GROUP BY task_date, 
         employee_name
```

Comment: That sqlfiddle is great, but it would be even better if you added you code and sample data here too. (sqlfiddle isn't always available, and not for years I suppose, which this SO posting is.)

Comment: Alright, thank you @jarlh I've upated the question area with the details.

Comment: I can't find your `where` condition, only `join` conditions.

Comment: Why the `ORDER BY` in the sub-query?

Comment: And why that second `AND a.region = b.region = 'USA'`? Should it perhaps be c.region?

Comment: By his input you can see all rows have USA region.. do I doubt it matter @jarlh

Comment: oops sorry, corrected the second `AND a.region = b.region = 'USA'` to `c.region`

Comment: Perhaps poor sample data... Add some different rows too!

Comment: Updated the fiddle link & sample data too.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - You're right. I've updated the question's subject & the content so that there is no confusion. Sorry about this. It's the `JOIN` condition I'm referring to as you've rightly spotted.

Comment: @jarlh - Would you be able to help me correct whatever is incorrect about the query please?

Comment: I've never even touched MySQL, but can you perhaps skip the SELECT DISTINCT sub-query and instead do `Group_concat(distinct task_name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join is on the full table "a" no matter the date so you need to add the where (see the **) and no need to put it in the join. I'm not sure but the CASE with IS NULL doesn't work everytime, i prefer to use a coalesce :

```
    SELECT   task_date, 
         employee_name, 
         Group_concat(task_name) 
FROM     ( 
                         SELECT DISTINCT a.task_date, 
                                         a.employee_name, 
                                         CASE 
                                                         WHEN b.employee_name IS NOT NULL
                                                                 AND  COALESCE(c.employee_name, '00') THEN '00'
                                                         ELSE a.task_name
                                         END       AS task_name 
                         FROM            forgerock AS a 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN forgerock AS b 
                         ON              a.employee_name = b.employee_name = 'A'
                         AND             b.task_date >= '2015-01-03' 
                         AND             b.task_date <= '2015-01-06' 
                         AND             a.task_date - 1 = b.task_date
                         AND             a.region = b.region = 'USA' 
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN forgerock AS c 
                         ON              a.employee_name = c.employee_name = 'A'
                         AND             c.task_date >= '2015-01-03' 
                         AND             c.task_date <= '2015-01-06' 
                         AND             a.task_date - 1 = c.task_date
                         AND             a.task_name <> c.task_name 
                         AND             a.region = b.region = 'USA' 
                         **WHERE  a.task_date >= '2015-01-03' AND   a.task_date <= '2015-01-06'**
                         ORDER BY        a.task_date, 
                                         a.employee_name, 
                                         a.task_name) AS temp 
GROUP BY task_date, 
         employee_name
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't test this in the fiddle. The fiddle keeps crashing. :-( I'll try this locally on a mysql instance & let you know

Comment: Perfect. It works as I wanted. Thank you very much. Appreciate your help. Good day :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with this query, but all your joins are left outer joins so the a table (the one from the FROM) will never be filtered. You should always check the query plan which for your query simply states no where condition on the a table:

[image]

Simple fix would be to specify a WHERE condition on the a table or switch to inner joins.

As performance is concerned you should again have a look at the query plan. If you are filtering a large table with no index (you see only *using where* in the query plan, example:

[image]

) that usually is a sign to perform a deeper investigation.

Comment: Thank you heaps.I'm trying to find the new tasks assigned to employees per day. I'd like to see the date & the newly assigned task compared to the previous day with respect to any particular day. If on day1, an employee is assigned task A & day2 he is again on task A, I should not see task A on day2.However if he was assigned task B on day2 & he comes back to task n day3, I should see task A as a new task on day3. basically compare today's task list to yesterdays & show what is new - This is the requirement. If you can help me implement this better, i'd be highly thankful to you.